# Iterated variable (i) for argument on range in Google Scripts API

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

```
  for (i=0; i<numItems; i++) {
    var cell = sheet.getRange(12,i);
    cell.setFormula(i);
  }
```

This simple formula should go to every place on the column 12 where there is data, and replace it with the number which i is, correct? The argument it is giving me is `The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid.`

How on earth am I supposed to use the i for the argument in range?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some inaccuracies in your code. I will try to guide you through the code.

1. Your code alone will not work, but you probably know that

   - first declare the active sheet (or spreadsheet)
     `var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();`
   - determine the last row in the sheet
     `var row = sh.getLastRow();`
   - get the range and get the values
     `var aData = sh.getRange(1, 2, row, 1).getValues();`
2. The `getRange(row, col)` will range a particular cell and not a range. After having set the `getRange()`, you need to get the content by adding the `getValues()`. The `setFormula()` is specifically meant for adding a formula, like `"=MAX(A:A)"`.
   Here's the ittaration, how I would perform it:

   - first, you need to hold the "new" data in an array
     `var aNew = new Array();`
   - set up the itteration
     `for (i=0; i<aData.length; i++) {`
   - set up an `IF` statement
     `if(aData[i][0] != "") {`
   - add "new" data into array via the push method
     `aNew.push([i+1]);`
3. Finally add the newly gathered data to the active sheet. This is done via the `setValues()` command.

   - `sh.getRange(1, 1, aNew.length, 1).setValues(aNew);`

The complete code and example file: **[itteration code](https://docs.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdFo5eU83aFpFNG9CN2EwRnRPR2RYS2c&usp=sharing)**

```
function myFunction() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var row = sh.getLastRow();
  var aData = sh.getRange(1, 2, row, 1).getValues(); 

  var aNew = new Array();  
  for (i=0; i<aData.length; i++) {
    if(aData[i][0] != "") {
      aNew.push([i+1]);
    }
  }
  sh.getRange(1, 1, aNew.length, 1).setValues(aNew);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same. The problem is that there is no row 0...

You should use `i+1`:

```
var cell = sheet.getRange(12,i+1);
```